# QLineEdit extended popup

Tags: c++, qt4

Idea for widget:
By default the widget is basically a QLineEdit where the user can input text. The QLineEdit can obviously only display a certain amount of character (limit). The idea would be that once the mentioned limit is reached, the widget should be extended with a popup window which is overlayed other GUI controls (like QComboBox poup window). This popup window would then contain the text which the "QLineEdit" could not show. The poup window size would need to be dynamic to handle multiple lines. When the widget loses focus it will show the QLineEdit box and part of the original text.

What would be a good design for this widget? Would it be possible to extend an existing widget or combine multiple widgets or ?

Tried looking at the QComboBox source code but it is rather complicated.

**Update:**[image: Here is a trivial example]

Comment: Is this good from a design point of view ? Why use a widget that you know won't be big enough ?

Comment: The QDialog has very limited space available and the size of the input text can vary greatly. Using QPlainTextEdit with two lines is not an option due to the space issue. This is the best option so far.

Comment: Can you add an image of your current design ?

Comment: Added an example to the original post. Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem I see is: How far should this widget be able to expand? Only within the parent widget or as a true popup? I think a popup can be a good idea, but you will need to create a new top-level widget (window) for it.

Comment: I think it's confusing because you have the other labels, Manufacturer, etc. Which one are you typing when it's expanded ? I think it would be better to make the line edits non-editable and react to clicking on them with a popup dialog

Comment: ypnos: I was thinking a true popup. What widget would be best suited to create as the popup?

Comment: koan: I see your point that the image might look confussing, hopefully the actual usage is more intuitive to the user. The opening and closing of the popup window would be controlled by focus in and focus out, so hopefully the user follows that logic.